# Yandex Ranking Leak - Which Specific Ranking Signal Should be a Focus?

Tags: seo, technical-seo, yandex

From the recent Yandex ranking Leak, https://searchengineland.com/yandex-search-ranking-factors-leak-392323 which of the following signals will have the most relevance for every site in 2023 on Google?

Rather than having an open question, I'd like to know specifically which 1 of those 6 signals should prevail as the primary factor of focus. I have my own views & insights, however I'd like to see if someone has data or recent findings of their own to suggest:

1. "PageRank and many link-related factors (e.g., age, relevancy, etc.)."
2. "Text relevancy."
3. "Content age and freshness."
4. "End-user behavior signals."
5. "Host reliability."
6. "Some sites get preference (e.g., Wikipedia)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the fact that I have simply incredible cases for Yandex, I will tell you this. You do basic optimization, and then you turn the normal behavioral factor and you will be TOP!

Comment: thank :) lol regards